# How does the API address for trained ML model look?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

In the projects.predict documentation it says that the api-url is:
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/**}:predict

But I dont understand how this looks in reality? Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI you use is:

https://ml.googleapis.com/projects/my_project/models/my_model:predict

Where `my_project` is of course the name of your project and `my_model` is the name you chose when you created the model.

You may want to check out one of the client libraries -- especially for authentication -- which are what the samples use. [This page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/online-predict#requesting_predictions) from the official documentation contains a Python sample; [this PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/pull/290) shows C#; and [this PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/pull/432) shows JavaScript. More to come.

Comment: If you want to send a request to a particular version of the model, rather than the default version, you can use the version-specific URI

`https://ml.googleapis.com/projects/my_project/models/my_model/versions/my_version:predict`